# Setting up Unity to build an app for the Gear VR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, oculus, gear-vr

I am following [this](http://www.samsung.com/us/samsungdeveloperconnection/developer-resources/gear-vr/apps-and-games/exercise-1-creating-a-unity-project.html) tutorial and I am stuck on "Setup Unity Integration". There is no such folder as `/VrSamples/Unity/UnityIntegration/` in Oculus Mobile SDK 1.0.0.1. It should contain unity package with OVR components and necessary project settings. Where can I find it?

Comment: If you just want to know about the gear vr setting, you do not need to the sample, just set on the `Virtual Reality Supported` in player setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in

> ovr_sdk_mobile_1.0.0.1/VrSamples/Unity/SDKExamples

It has project Settings and the OVR components.